# How to convert a datetime into date without changing the data type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to split this `TimeStamp` column without changing data format?

I have a column `TimeStamp` which is in `datetime` format, and I just want to keep the date part (in `datetime` format).

I tried to use

```
CONVERT(DATE, "TimeStamp")
```

it shows only the date part, but the format is `nvarchar(10)`.

SQL Code:

```
SELECT 
    "TimeStamp",
    CONVERT(DATE, "TimeStamp") AS Date
```

My expected result:

```
TimeStamp (datetime)    Date (datatype: datetime)
------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-10 07:30:25     2017-03-10
2017-03-10 07:30:28     2017-03-10
2017-03-10 07:31:30     2017-03-10
2017-03-10 07:31:39     2017-03-10
```

Comment: The conversion does return a Date, not nvarchar, as it should when I tested on MSSQL 2016. Where do you get a nvarchar as a result?

Comment: Hi Sami, I checked the result again, it showed the date part as above but datatype is nvarchar(10). I dont know what is the problem.

Comment: How did you check the datatype? If I use `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` to get the datatype it says `date`.

Comment: Do you insert result of this query into some table with column of type `nvarchar(10)`? Also your requirement to convert from type1 to type2 but that the result had type1 is unreasonable...

Answer (score 3):

Tysss I have made a demo for you please try this, Here I have used `GETDATE()` for return current date with a timestamp where you have to pass your column name as you showed in the question which is `TimeStamp`.

**SOLUTION 1**

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),110) AS DATE) AS DATE
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2019-05-17
```

**SOLUTION 2**

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),110) AS DATETIME) AS DATE
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2019-05-17 00:00:00.000
```

I think you need the only date from TimeStamp so, you need to change the datatype `DATE` else if you will keep your datatype `DATETIME` then it will return date something like `2019-05-17 00:00:00.000`

Comment: using as `SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATE` enough I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
select GETDATE() as TimeStamp,
convert(date, getdate()) as date
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post result of that screenshot as text (if you find attaching result neccessary) or at least trim it as most of this image is white background and tooltip hides the query anyway?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate());

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  **CAST**(TRANSDATE AS **DATE**) as TransDate
FROM Vendtrans

Comment: In this query I just transfer the field called TRANSDATE into date, from the table called VENDTRANS